# Electricity categorization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to categorize which electronic devices that are turned ON based only the sum of all electricity for my apartment. I have a setup where I measure each watt hour (blink of a LED), so the current consumption in watts have a precision of about 10 seconds, which is great.

I am trying to do this in tensorflow, and in the first iteration I want to use only one input (the total watts, e.g. 200W), and I want to have one output per electronic device. I also use dummy data now to see how it works (and because it would be very troublesome to categorize every measurement to be able to teach the algorithm).

Here is my code now:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

LABELS = [
'Nothing',
'Toaster',  # Toaster uses 800W
'Lamp']  # Lamp uses just 100W

DATA_LENGTH = 20000

np.random.seed(1)  # To be able to reproduce

# Create dummy data (1:s or 0:s)
nothing_data = np.array([1] * DATA_LENGTH)
toaster_data = np.random.randint(2, size=DATA_LENGTH)
lamp_data = np.random.randint(2, size=DATA_LENGTH)

labels = np.array(list(zip(nothing_data, toaster_data, lamp_data)))

x_train = (toaster_data * 800 + lamp_data * 100) / 900  # Normalize
y_train = labels

# Split up train and test data
x_test = x_train[15000:]
y_test = y_train[15000:]
x_train = x_train[:15000]
y_train = y_train[:15000]

# The model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_dim=1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adadelta',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(val_loss, val_acc)
```

Now to the problem, the val_acc is 1.0, 100%. (val_loss=0.059, val_acc=1.0)
Still when I predict, the predictions are very off.

```
# Predict
predict_input = [0.88888, 0.111111, 1.0000, 0.222]
predict_output = model.predict(predict_input)
```

First one should be toaster + nothing, but it also has 33% lamp. I would have liked binary output, if that was possible.

Do I need to have a "nothing" output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the model type to your problem.  You've applied what is basically a mixed linear regression prediction, to a problem of binary classification.  The model is good if you want to predict that wattage, given the appliances turned on, but it's not so good in the opposite direction.

It's going to try all sorts of things with the paucity of data given and the freedom inherent in the model.  Note that you really have only four training inputs: making multiple copies in equal amounts doesn't really make your training better.

Most of all, why are you *not* doing this with the "sum to target" algorithm, a much simpler and more effective way to solve the problem.  The presented problem isn't really a ML sort of problem.

If you simply *want* to do this by training a model, then build one with multiple binary outputs.  You can research "multiple labels" for leads on how to do so.  If you're doing it only for a handful of appliances in your home, you might want to beat it to death with 2^n output states, and not worry about the structural accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will check "sum to target" algorithm. I am a absolute beginner in AI and wanted to learn more so I just gave it a shot. 

If I instead of using a single input, use multiple inputs over time, e.g. 100 measurements, it would also be possible to match over time, but then the data set might become much larger?

Comment: I see.  For *that* level of information, you seem to be on the wrong site.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.  Most of all, you have a lot of reading and a lot of fun ahead of you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Prune